# Deleting data from a list from a second form

Tags: c#

I have a form that where I read in a csv file containing student information, the file has two columns `StudentNumber` and `Mark`. I want to allow the user to click a button on the first form to then go to another form called `deleteRecord` On this form the user will type in a `StudentNumber` and a `Mark` and the record that corresponds with them two pieces of information will be delete from the list.

Since I am new to C# I am not sure on how to go about this so any help will be appreciated.

My list:

`public static List<string> studentInfo = new List<string>();`

I store all the data from that list in a listbox called lstMarks

I want to also confirm to the user that the record was deleted successfully.

Comment: It's always only two columns, student number and their Mark?

Comment: yes there is only 2 collumns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the data is stored in the list, simply use LINQ and add a number for each student in the list for the index.

First you'll need to create a class and (I recommend it) put it in a folder.
[How it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVbzT.png)

Then you'll have to put the propreties in the class:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int StudentNumber {get; set;}
    public int Mark {get; set;}
    public int Index {get; set;}
}
```

Now add another class with the list:

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<Student> _studentInfo = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student() {Index = 0, StudentNumber = 0, Mark = 0}
        // ...
    }
```

And then add using at the top of your code of deleteRecord and the name of the folder and the two classes:

```cs
using ExampleFolder.Class;
```

You'll need to call your Student class to be able to modify the StudentNumber and Mark and Index.

```cs
Student studentInfo = new Student();
```

```cs
    int iIndex = 0;

    var req = from info in studentInfo
              where info.StudentNumber == txtStudentNumber && info.Mark == txtMarks
              select info.Index; // Starts with 0 for the first student in the list
    foreach(var num in req)
    {
        iIndex = num;
    }
    studentInfo.Remove(studentInfo[iIndex]);

    MessageBox.Show("Deleted!");
```

Comment: From your code, When it get execute, i see only one record get deleted no mater how many records user select. Instead you can put delete inside foreach loop and user have multiple selection at once, it will be much better.

Comment: The best would be making a ListView with all the students and their info and then just click on the one you want to delete and use SelectedIndex and then press a button to delete it.

Comment: What form would I put this code on? the first form or the deleteRecord form

Comment: From the place the user clicks or confirm to delete.

Comment: I am getting an error "The name studentInfo doesn't exist in the current context" how do I make it so that I can use the list on this form? this goes for txtStudent and txtMarks.

Comment: It depends on how your code is built. I just used txtStudent because I thought your textbox were named that way. for the list you need to put it in a class and I recommend making it public and putting it in a folder. Then from your deleteRecord. At the top of your code add : using "name of your solution"."the folder the class is";

Comment: So is it okay if I added the list to the first form and made it public? and what do you mean "The folder the class is"

Comment: @Darren_D19, Please read the latest updated answer from Voxaim. I hope it will be clear enough and solve your issue. Please accept the answer at the end it will help to increase the reputation. Thanks